# Problems in Generating the Reference List with TexMaker

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I have my `.tex` file as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib} % for the bibliography

\begin{document}

A much longer \LaTeXe{} example was written by Gil~\cite{label1}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\newpage \bibliography{Weekly Report 10}

\end{document}
```

My `Weekly Report 10.bib` file is as follows:

```
@InProceedings{label1,
author = {author},
title = {title},
booktitle = {booktitle},
OPTcrossref = {OPTcrossref},
OPTkey = {OPTkey},
OPTpages = {OPTpages},
OPTyear = {OPTyear},
OPTeditor = {OPTeditor},
OPTvolume = {OPTvolume},
OPTnumber = {OPTnumber},
OPTseries = {OPTseries},
OPTaddress = {OPTaddress},
OPTmonth = {OPTmonth},
OPTorganization = {OPTorganization},
OPTpublisher = {OPTpublisher},
OPTnote = {OPTnote},
OPTannote = {OPTannote}
}
```

I have them together in one folder.

I have also run PDFLaTeX first, and then BibTeX, and then PDFLaTeX twice more.

However, **my reference list is always empty**. The error messages are as follows:

[image]

Where goes wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can not use bibliography filenames with spaces. So, renaming your bibliography from `Weekly Report 10.bib` to `WeeklyReport10.bib` and using `\bibliography{WeeklyReport10}` should solve it.

Comment: @karlkoeller thank you so much! it solves my problem. You may post it as the answer so that the reputation can be rewarded to you. :) Also, may I ask there is any general guidelines in LaTeX about the space? sometimes it is allowed and sometimes it is prohibited...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can not use spaces in bibliography filenames, because BibTeX doesn't recognize them as valid characters.

So, renaming your bibliography from `Weekly Report 10.bib` to `WeeklyReport10.bib` and changing

```
\bibliography{Weekly Report 10}
```

to

```
\bibliography{WeeklyReport10}
```

in your document will solve the problem.

Remember that in other places filenames with spaces are "tolerated" and not "allowed", so the best practice is: **never use spaces in filenames**